# Keycloack - get accessToken via Password grantType - requires client_secret

Tags: keycloak

As a newbie of Keycloak, I try to configure a client with a "Password" grant type. I know that this is not the preferred solution in most cases.

I created a realm 'realm2' with a client 'myclient2' and a user.

When trying to get the token with Postman, I get this error:

> ```
> {
>     "error": "unauthorized_client",
>     "error_description": "Client secret not provided in request"
> }
> ```

When I add the client_secret, I get the token. I tried to provide a username and password and no secret.

Via the Keycloak user interface I can also login as 'johan' in the 'realm2'.

This is my request in Postman:

[image]

In Keycloak I configured the 'realm2' with no special properties set:

[image]

The client 'myclient2' is:

[image]

I can see on the Credentials tab of the client:

[image]

I configured 1 user in the realm2 with just 'password' as a password:

[image]

How can I configure my Keycloack settings so I don't need the 'secret' but the username and password?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could disable authentication for the client, making it public. You can do this by turning off "Client authentication" under the settings tab of your client.

EDIT: I just realized your keycloak version seems different to mine. This configuration is likely under the `Access Type` selector in your settings tab, by changing it from `confidential` to `public`

Answer (score 1):

In order to retrieve user identity by a client, non-interactively (background service, without user interface), provided that this client knows the user credentials, using OAuth 2 / OpenID standards, and Keycloak server, here's how to do it using OAuth 2.0 Password Grant. Note that this is for legacy purposes and has been removed in OAuth 2.1.

First, we disable all interactive flows (standard, implicit) and leave only the Direct Access Grants:

[image]

For a public client, specify the client_id, audience, username, password, grant_type (password) and scope (openid):

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://keycloak:8080/auth/realms/<your-realm>/protocol/openid-connect/token' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=password' \
--data-urlencode 'audience=<your-client-id>' \
--data-urlencode 'username=johan' \
--data-urlencode 'password=12345678' \
--data-urlencode 'scope=openid' \
--data-urlencode 'client_id=<your-client-id>'
```

For confidential, add client_secret:

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://keycloak:8080/auth/realms/<your-realm>/protocol/openid-connect/token' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=password' \
--data-urlencode 'audience=<your-client-id>' \
--data-urlencode 'username=johan' \
--data-urlencode 'password=12345678' \
--data-urlencode 'scope=openid' \
--data-urlencode 'client_id=<your-client-id>' \
--data-urlencode 'client_secret=<your-client-secret>'
```

Note: In my case, client_id and client_secret can also be used using HTTP Basic Authentication, but only for confidential clients.

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://earth.eastnets.com:8080/auth/realms/eastnets/protocol/openid-connect/token' \
--header 'Authorization: Basic YW1sY2xpZW50OmFtbHNlY3JldA==' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=password' \
--data-urlencode 'audience=<your-client-id>' \
--data-urlencode 'username=johan' \
--data-urlencode 'password=12345678' \
--data-urlencode 'scope=openid'
```

For password to be verified *you need to configure default Authentication flow for Direct Grant ( / Authentication / Flows) to require Password, the change will be globally for all clients:

[image]

Otherwise, Copy the flow to a new name, for example, Direct Grant Strict, edit that one and override the Authentication flow for direct grants for a particular client, as shown below, in the Client configuration:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

@Haf answer is right to the point; **TL;DR:** In the client `Access Type` dropdown menu select *public* instead of *confidential*.

Nonetheless, I want to add a bit more information behind the scenes since you stated that:

> As a newbie for Keycloack I try to configure a client with a
> "Password" grant type.

First, you should know that Keycloak implements OpenID Connect, which

> [is a simple identity layer on top of the OAuth 2.0 protocol.](https://openid.net/connect/)

According to the OAuth 2.0 protocol clients can be either **confidential** or **public**.

> The main difference relates to whether or not the application is able
> to hold credentials (such as a client ID and secret) securely.

Regarding the **confidential** clients:

> Because they use a trusted backend server, **confidential applications**
> can use grant types that require them to authenticate by specifying
> **their client ID and client secret** when calling the Token endpoint.

Armed with this knowledge you can easily figure it out how to create a client that will not have a client secret.