# Spring security - using WebClient access a resource that is protected via Oauth2 "Password" grant type

Tags: spring-security, spring-webclient, spring-oauth2

How can I access with WebClient a resource that is protected via the Oauth2 'Password' grant type?

Connecting with Oauth2 'client-credentials' works. In this case I need the password grant type.

I get this error:

```
401 Unauthorized from GET http://localhost:8086/test2 at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientResponseException.create(WebClientResponseException.java:198) ~[spring-webflux-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
    *__checkpoint ⇢ 401 from GET http://localhost:8086/test2
```

I configured the auth server via Keycloack with Access Type 'public'. I checked accessing a token via Postman. You can find more details via [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75270121/3143823).

[image]

The Websecurity config (working for grant-type client-credentials):

```
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("*").permitAll();
    }
}
```

The webclient is created as a Bean. It works for the client-credentials grant type.

```
@Configuration
public class WebClientOAuth2Config {
    @Bean("method2")
    WebClient webClientGrantPassword( @Qualifier("authclientmgr2") OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager2) {
        ServletOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction oauth2Client2 =
                        new ServletOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction(
                        authorizedClientManager2);
        oauth2Client2.setDefaultClientRegistrationId("businesspartners");
        return WebClient.builder().apply(oauth2Client2.oauth2Configuration()).build();
    }

    @Bean("authclientmgr2")
    public OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager2(
                    ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository,
                    OAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository authorizedClientRepository) {

        OAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider authorizedClientProvider = OAuth2AuthorizedClientProviderBuilder.builder()
                        .clientCredentials()
                        .build();

        DefaultOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager = new DefaultOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager(
                        clientRegistrationRepository, authorizedClientRepository);
        authorizedClientManager.setAuthorizedClientProvider(authorizedClientProvider);

        return authorizedClientManager;
    }
}
```

The controller accessing the resource server:

```
@RestController
public class Test2Controller {
  @Autowired
  private @Qualifier("method2") WebClient webClient2;

  @GetMapping("/test2")
  public String test2() {
    return webClient2.get().uri("http://localhost:8086/test2")
            .attributes(clientRegistrationId("businesspartners"))
            .retrieve().bodyToMono(String.class).block();
  }
}
```

The application.yml config is:

```
server:
  port: 8081

spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          businesspartners:
            client-id: myclient2
            authorization-grant-type: password
            client-name: johan
            client-secret: password
        provider:
          businesspartners:
            issuer-uri: http://localhost:28080/auth/realms/realm2
            token-uri: http://localhost:28080/auth/realms/realm2/protocol/openid-connect/token
```

The maven dependencies include:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure whether it's possible to do it using `application.yml` but here is how you can configure it in code

```
private ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction oauth(
        String clientRegistrationId, SecurityConfig config) {
    var clientRegistration = ClientRegistration
            .withRegistrationId(clientRegistrationId)
            .clientAuthenticationMethod(ClientAuthenticationMethod.NONE)
            .tokenUri(config.getTokenUri() + "/token")
            .clientId(config.getClientId())
            .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.PASSWORD)
            .build();

    var authRepository = new InMemoryReactiveClientRegistrationRepository(clientRegistration);
    var authClientService = new InMemoryReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientService(authRepository);

    var authClientManager = new AuthorizedClientServiceReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager(
            authRepository, authClientService);

    var clientAuthProvider = new PasswordReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider();
    authClientManager.setAuthorizedClientProvider(clientAuthProvider);
    authClientManager.setContextAttributesMapper(authorizeRequest ->  Mono.just(
            Map.of(
                    OAuth2AuthorizationContext.USERNAME_ATTRIBUTE_NAME, config.getUsername(),
                    OAuth2AuthorizationContext.PASSWORD_ATTRIBUTE_NAME, config.getPassword()
            )
    ));

    var oauth = new ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction(authClientManager);
    oauth.setDefaultClientRegistrationId(clientRegistrationId);
    return oauth;
}
```

and then use in in `WebClient`

```
WebClient webClient = WebClient.builder()
      .filter(oauth("businesspartners", securityConfig))
      .build();
```

where `SecurityConfig` is defined like

```
@lombok.Value
@lombok.Builder
static class SecurityConfig {
    String tokenUri;
    String clientId;
    String username;
    String password;
}
```

Here is a full test using `WireMock`

```
@Slf4j
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = NONE)
@AutoConfigureWireMock(port = 0) // random port
class WebClientTest {

    @Value("${wiremock.server.port}")
    private int wireMockPort;

    @Test
    void authClientTest() {
        String authResponse = """
                {
                  "token_type": "Bearer",
                  "expires_in": 3599,
                  "ext_expires_in": 3599,
                  "access_token": "token",
                  "refresh_token": "token"
                }""";

        stubFor(post(urlPathMatching("/token"))
                .withRequestBody(
                        containing("client_id=myclient2")
                                .and(containing("grant_type=password"))
                                .and(containing("password=password"))
                                .and(containing("username=username"))
                )
                .withHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, containing(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED.toString()))
                .willReturn(aResponse()
                        .withHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                        .withStatus(200)
                        .withBody(authResponse)
                )
        );

        stubFor(get(urlPathMatching("/test"))
                .willReturn(aResponse()
                        .withHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                        .withStatus(200)
                        .withBody("{}")
                )
        );

        SecurityConfig config = SecurityConfig.builder()
                .tokenUri("http://localhost:" + wireMockPort)
                .clientId("myclient2")
                .username("username")
                .password("password")
                .build();

        WebClient webClient = WebClient.builder()
                .baseUrl("http://localhost:" + wireMockPort)
                .filter(oauth("test", config))
                .build();

        Mono<String> request = webClient.get()
                .uri("/test")
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(String.class);

        StepVerifier.create(request)
                .assertNext(res -> log.info("response: {}", res))
                .verifyComplete();
    }

    private ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction oauth(
            String clientRegistrationId, SecurityConfig config) {
        var clientRegistration = ClientRegistration
                .withRegistrationId(clientRegistrationId)
                .clientAuthenticationMethod(ClientAuthenticationMethod.NONE)
                .tokenUri(config.getTokenUri() + "/token")
                .clientId(config.getClientId())
                .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.PASSWORD)
                .build();

        var authRepository = new InMemoryReactiveClientRegistrationRepository(clientRegistration);
        var authClientService = new InMemoryReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientService(authRepository);

        var authClientManager = new AuthorizedClientServiceReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager(
                authRepository, authClientService);

        var clientAuthProvider = new PasswordReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider();
        authClientManager.setAuthorizedClientProvider(clientAuthProvider);
        authClientManager.setContextAttributesMapper(authorizeRequest ->  Mono.just(
                Map.of(
                        OAuth2AuthorizationContext.USERNAME_ATTRIBUTE_NAME, config.getUsername(),
                        OAuth2AuthorizationContext.PASSWORD_ATTRIBUTE_NAME, config.getPassword()
                )
        ));

        var oauth = new ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction(authClientManager);
        oauth.setDefaultClientRegistrationId(clientRegistrationId);
        return oauth;
    }

    @lombok.Value
    @lombok.Builder
    static class SecurityConfig {
        String tokenUri;
        String clientId;
        String username;
        String password;
    }
}
```